# React Router v6 - Handle both external hrefs and interal paths

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In my react app with react-router v6 I am retrieving links dynamically that can be either a regular external url (like https://stackoverflow.com/) or an internal path (like `"/my-page"`) that corresponds to a Route with `react-router`.

So far, when using `react-router-dom`'s `<Link>` component, I could only get it to work with an internal path, but NOT with an external url. As far as I understood the docs I couldn't find a way to achieve this, at least not with v6.

So the best approach I've come up with so far is to write an own `MyLink` component that either render an `<a>` or a `<Link>` depending on whether the href is external or not:

```
function MyLink(props) {
  const isHrefExternal = props.href.match(/^http|^https|^www/);

  if (isHrefExternal) {
    return <a href={props.href}>{props.children}</a>;
  }

  return <Link to={props.href}>{props.children}</Link>;
}
```

This of course doesn't look like a very good solution:

- The check for `isHrefExternal` is very naive
- It's unclear what props `MyLink` should accept and how they should be managed since `<a>` and `<Link>` have different props.

For a full example see this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-breeze-g3xmt2?file=/src/App.js:80-310)

Can you tell me how to do it better? Ideally there would be an option to pass an external url to `react-router-dom`'s `<Link>` component but I couldn't find one.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The `Link` component handles only internal links within your app, and likely [won't ever handle external links natively](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8410). I don't see any overt issues with your code, what makes you think it isn't a good solution? The "isExternal" check may be naive, but it only needs to cover your specific use cases. As new use cases are required you can tweak the logic for this check. In my projects I've just typically included an `isExternal` property with the fetched links so the app doesn't even need to think about it.

Comment: thanks. I think that's right and the `isExternal` approach might be the best solution. Especially the github link convinced me. If you want to post the comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: One thing to note is React-Router does handle both incoming external and internal links. So if you manually browse to http://localhost/my-page/12345 it will be processed by the correct route as if you performed a <Link ... /> to /my-page/12345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Link component handles only internal links within your app, and likely [won't ever handle external links natively](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8410).

I don't see any overt issues with your code, and I don't think it's a bad solution. The "isExternal" check *may* be naive, but it only needs to cover your specific use cases. As new use cases are required you can tweak the logic for this check. In my projects I've worked with we've just typically included an `isExternal` type property with fetched data so the app doesn't even need to think about what is or isn't an external link, it just checks the flag when rendering.